# mod_rewrite: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm running Apache 2.4 and PHP 5.6 on linux and have noticed the following error  **when user visit not exist file or direcrtory (example: /test/1.asp or /aa/ )in this website**:

**Broswer display：**

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@xxx.edu to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

**Apache error log:**

```
[core:error] [pid 12843] [client 202.xxx.xxx.xxx:64587] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

**.htaccess file:**

```
Options -MultiViews
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(en|zh|ja|ko)/(.*)$ $2?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?lang=zh [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

**The rewrite rule doing:**

```
http://www.example.com/en =>  http://www.example.com/index.php?lang=en 
http://www.example.com/jo =>  http://www.example.com/index.php?lang=jo
http://www.example.com/zh =>  http://www.example.com/index.php?lang=zh
```

**Default：**

```
http://www.example.com =>  http://www.example.com/index.php?lang=zh
```

It should **return 404 error when user visit not exist file or direcrtory** in this website, not "Internal Server Error".

How to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try something with this

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://yourdomain.com/
```

You have also 3 conditions and 3 rules. The first condition will be executed when the 3 conditions become true. The 2 others will be executed without condition. I'm not sure it is your intention. 
Think also in loops, everytime a [L] Flag passes a new iteration starts.

**UPDATE**

In your case also an option is (simplified example), go then from there

```
RewriteEngine On

# check if language exists do redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(en|zh|ja|ko)
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ ?lang=$1 [L,QSA]

# if not found go to your 404 page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(en|zh|ja|ko)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /404.html [R=404,L]
```

See also [Apache mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to get a feeling and understanding for mod_rewrite and what is happening.

Comment: Thank you, Michael.  I added more detail info to the question.

Comment: Updated new example